# jsPlumb - bad position of endpoints after refresh and after mouseover they get to good position

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsplumb

I have a problem with jsPlumb endpoints. After site refresh, the position of endpoints is not on draggable elements but somewhere else on the site. But after mouseover they skip on good position. I have no idea why. The initial elements have absolute position set by left and top css properties.

Dragable elements:

```
<div class="window" id="flowchartWindow5"></div>
<div class="window" id="flowchartWindow1"><strong>1</strong></div>
<div class="window" id="flowchartWindow2"><strong>2</strong></div>
<div class="window" id="flowchartWindow3"></div>
<div class="window" id="flowchartWindow4"></div>
```

Thanx for help...

Answer (score 4):

Without your actual code it is difficult to say why elements are misplaced but you can try to repaint the connections after the page loads as the elements might have been moved after initial connection.
Include the below code at the end of your JS or after page loads:

```
jsPlumb.repaintEverything();
```

In order to help you out better include jsFiddle link!